# How to hide the wait cursor while loading windows mobile program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have an application written in C# and running on Windows Mobile 5.  It currently takes several seconds to load all of the assemblies.  During that time the wait cursor spins on top of the screen.  I would like to show a splash screen with a progress bar instead.  How can I prevent the cursor from being displayed?

Comment: Display a splash screen.  First call to GetMessage() turns off the wait cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The CF execution engine (i.e. mscoree) itself makes the call to set the wait cursor, and this happens before it even starts JITting code.  There's no way to hook into that and no registry entry (known or undocumented) that can turn the behavior off.